# Can I add ssl certificate in google kubernetes deployed app without ingress?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, socket.io, google-kubernetes-engine

When I create an `ingress` and add a `ssl-certificate`, it automatically restarts after every 30 sec. My `socket.io` is disconnected and reconnected after every 30 sec as well.

I don't want the `socket.io` to disconnect and connect every 30 seconds. How can I tackle this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue you have is the [default backend timeout](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/backend-service#timeout-setting) for Ingress is 30 seconds.  You'll need to create a [BackendConfig resource](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/ingress-configuration#configuring_ingress_features_through_backendconfig_parameters) where you set the timeout and attach it to your Service:

```
apiVersion: cloud.google.com/v1
kind: BackendConfig
metadata:
  name: my-backendconfig
spec:
  timeoutSec:  2147483647
```